# until a valid one is entered with while loop.I need a while but where?

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to modify the program with while loop to continually prompt the user for a password.

```
def user_input():
    """ takes input from user """
    input1 = input("Enter a password : ")
    if length_check(input1) != True or char_check(input1) != True:
        exit()
    elif length_check(input1) and char_check(input1):
        input2 = input("Reenter password: ")

    return input1, input2


def check_passwords(input1, input2):
    """
    Compute and return the acceleration due to gravity. Normally this would be
    a single line Docstring, like in function1, but I wanted to provide an
    example of a multiline docstring. You can use these when a function needs
    extra explanation.
    """
    if input1 == input2:
        print("Password changed.")
    elif input2 != input1:
        print("Password not changed.")

    

def length_check(input1):
    if len(input1) <= 8:
        print("Password too short. Minimum length is 8 characters.")
        return False
    else:
        return True


def char_check(input1):
    uppercase = []
    numbers = list(range(0, 10))
    for i in range(65, 91):
        uppercase.append(chr(i))

    counter = 0
    for i in input1:  # Batman Surfs
        if i in uppercase:
            counter += 1
    # print(counter)
    if counter >= 2:
        if not any(char.isdigit() for char in input1):
            print('Password should have at least one numeral')
            return False
        else:
            return True

        # for i in input1:#Batman Surfs 1
        #     if i in numbers:
        #         return True
        #     else:
        #         print("Password must contain at least one number.")
        #         return False

    else:
        print("Password must contain at least two uppercase letters.")
        return False


def main():
    """ Explain WHAT main() is doing """

    input1, input2 = user_input()

    char_check(input1)
    check_passwords(input1, input2)

    # function1(12, 13)
    # m_e = 5  # mass in kg
    # r_e = 6  # radius in metres
    # gravity_on_earth = function2(m_e, r_e)
    # print(gravity_on_earth)

main()
```

Comment: just change line 5 from ```exit()``` to ```return user_input()```. not exactly using ```while``` but using recursive instead

Comment: your answer is super but teacher wants us to use while :<

Comment: Modify the program function to continually prompt the user for a password until a valid one is entered. Your solution must use a while loop. The functionality from previous parts should remain.
Enter a new password: batman
Password too short. Minimum length is 8 characters.
Enter a new password: batman rocks
Password must contain at least two uppercase characters.
Enter a new password: Batman Rocks
Password must contain at least one number.
Enter a new password: Batman Rocks 1
Reenter password: Batman Rocks 1
Password changed.

Comment: edit your question to add those details rather than posting it as comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `user_input()` function to return `None` (`NULL` value in python) when the input is not valid

```py
def user_input():
    """ takes input from user """
    input1 = input("Enter a password : ")
    if length_check(input1) != True or char_check(input1) != True:
        # exit() # deleted
        return None, None # added
    elif length_check(input1) and char_check(input1):
        input2 = input("Reenter password: ")

    return input1, input2
```

Change `main()` function to loop `while` input is not valid (we know it's not valid if it returns `None`)

```py
def main():
    """ Explain WHAT main() is doing """

    input1, input2 = user_input()
    while input1 == None and input2 == None: # added
        input1, input2 = user_input() # added

    char_check(input1)
    check_passwords(input1, input2)

    # function1(12, 13)
    # m_e = 5  # mass in kg
    # r_e = 6  # radius in metres
    # gravity_on_earth = function2(m_e, r_e)
    # print(gravity_on_earth)
    # enter code here # deleted


main()
```

I added comment with `# added` for lines that I add, and comment with `# deleted` for lines that I delete from your code.